# Is there a way to filter input type with gets() in C?

Tags: c

I have code that takes in a specified number of inputs and returns them as an alphabetized list. However, I can't quite work out how to exclude any ints that are input. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main(){
    int i, j, num_Words;
    char str[25][25],temp[25];

    puts("How many words do you want to sort? ");
    scanf("%d",&num_Words);

    puts("Enter your words one by one: ");

    for(i = 0; i <= num_Words; i++)
       gets(str[i]);

    for(i = 0; i <= num_Words; i++)
       for(j = i+1; j <= num_Words; j++){
          if(strcmp(str[i],str[j])>0){
             strcpy(temp,str[i]);
             strcpy(str[i],str[j]);
             strcpy(str[j],temp);
          }
       }

    printf("Sorted List:");
    for(i = 0; i <= num_Words; i++)
       puts(str[i]);

    return 0;
 }
```

Sample input:

```
cat
dog
17
bird
```

Desired output:

```
bird
cat
dog
```

What I'm actually getting:

```
17
bird
cat
dog
```

Comment: 0) `gets` has already been abolished. You should not use it.

Comment: 1) `i <= num_Words` --> `i < num_Words && i < 25`

Comment: Any code using `gets()` is woefully broken. [The `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)  That's why it is no longer a part of Standard C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggestion like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool validates(const char *word){
    if(!word || !*word)
        return false;

    while(*word){
        if(!isalpha((unsigned char)*word++))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

#define WORD_SIZE 25
#define NUM_OF_WORD 25

int main(void){
    int i, j, num_Words, valid_input;
    char str[NUM_OF_WORD][WORD_SIZE], temp[WORD_SIZE];

    puts("How many words do you want to sort? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_Words);
    while(getchar() != '\n');//clear upto newline

    puts("Enter your words one by one: ");

    for(valid_input = i = 0; i < num_Words && i < NUM_OF_WORD; i++){
        if(NULL == fgets(str[valid_input], sizeof *str, stdin))//Use fgets instead of gets
            break;
        str[valid_input][strcspn(str[valid_input], "\n")] = '\0';//chomp newline
        if(validates(str[valid_input])){//filtering
            ++valid_input;
        }
    }
    num_Words = valid_input;
    for(i = 0; i < num_Words - 1; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < num_Words; j++){
            if(strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0){
                strcpy(temp, str[i]);
                strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted List:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < num_Words; i++)
       puts(str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 for(i = 0; i <= num_Words; i++)
       for(j = i+1; j <= num_Words; j++){
          if(strcmp(str[i],str[j])>0){
             strcpy(temp,str[i]);
             strcpy(str[i],str[j]);
             strcpy(str[j],temp);
          }
       }
```

To

```
for(i = 0; i <= num_Words; i++)
       for(j = i+1; j <= num_Words; j++){
          if(strcmp(str[i],str[j])>0 && test(str[i]) && test(str[j])){
             strcpy(temp,str[i]);
             strcpy(str[i],str[j]);
             strcpy(str[j],temp);
          }
       }
```

Also make sure to add `#include<ctype.h>` as header.

I have created a function called test that takes the string and checks character by character to make sure it not a integer.

```
bool test(char x[])
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; ++i)
  {
    if(!isalpha(x[i])) return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: When I did this I received the following errors: "passing argument 1 of 'isalpha' makes integer from pointer without a cast" and "expected int but argument is of type char*."